# How restrictive is Steam's "Discovery 2.0" feature?

Tags: steam

Since the discovery 2.0 update Valve heavily changed which games you see first in shop and which not. 
You will get more personalized suggestions and see more games based on recommendations from your friends and favorite curators.

I am a bit anxious to get stuck into a filter-bubble.

So how does the "discovery" -system work exactly (based on which parameters)? 
Is my concern about the filter-bubble reasonable?

Comment: In this age of recommender systems, filter bubbles are a fact of life. What I usually do is browse Steam anonymously to get out of the bubble once in a while. Arqade is also good in hearing about games which do not typically show up in my recommendations.

Comment: Also keep in mind that "Discovery 2.0" is a proprietary thing developed and owned by Valve. It uses an unknown number of factors from any number of sources and unless Valve decides to tell everyone how it works (they won't), there's no real way to decidedly know how it all works. Anecdotal evidence on the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's based on what tags you look at most often. If someone were to look at games marked with Sandbox, then games tagged with Sandbox would be shown to them.

Comment: That's just one small piece of the puzzle, but it is correct ;)